# Is it 'bad' to have wrapper classes?

Tags: python

Someone on IRC told me it is bad to use classes as wrapper - Someone of whom I think he has some experience with python
I'm from .NET where it is common practice to use wrapper classes

**Why should it be bad style to use wrapper classes?**

Of course I could use a tulpe - but I can't see any benefit in it.
As [volcano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1381627/volcano) said, tulpes are also immutable
Also they are not inheritable

Wrapper class

```
class Movie(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = ''
        self.plot = ''
        ...
    # no functions / methods in here - only variables
```

Use `Movie` within this class

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        movie = Movie()
        movie.title = 'Ice Age'
```

Comment: This looks like a job for [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

Comment: @user2357112, depends. namedtuple are immutable

Comment: If you're not using a `class` as a proper class then you're effectively using it as a namespace, and the namespace part of a class is effectively a `dict`.... so you might as well just use: `movie = {'title': 'Ice Age'}` and use `['title']` access (you could use a variation of a `dict` that supports attribute access if you really wanted)... If you wanted restricted attribute creation, then you could use a class with `__slots__`, or there's other ways for other behaviour, but you almost certainly don't need a `Movie` class  (as shown) unless it's an actual class....

Answer (score 1):

You see this a fair bit with sqlalchemy, where a model might be defined as:

```
class Note(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'notes'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, unique=True)
    html = Column(Text)
    created = Column(DateTime)
    tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=note_tags)

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text, unique=True)
```

...and then a helper class exists with various operations on it, so that that model can easily be understood at a glance by looking at the classes in one file, rather than having distracting helper functions laid out endlessly underneath.

I don't see any particular reason why it's a terrible idea.

You shouldn't use class functions, typically. This may be where the comments are originating? Namespaces (modules) already perform that role.

ie. If you have a class Foo, and you're often using:

```
package.Foo.bar(...)
```

Simple place the bar method directly inside the package, and use it like this:

```
package.bar(...)
```

There is no need to put functions like this on a class; which is a very common c# pattern. ...but it only applies to class functions, and static functions where there's not really any meaningful reason for them to be attached to a class.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but the comment may be directed at avoiding an [anemic domain model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model), as prominently [hated by Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). In short, those guys ask the question: “Why use OO in the first place, when you're only using DTOs anyways. DTO are Data Transfer Objects, i.e. objects without behavior, more like structs. Those guys like to have [entities and value objects](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/13/ddd-entities-and-value-objects.aspx).

It's hard to tell for sure though what your friend meant, since there are many schools of thoughts regarding OO design.

As it is, your wrapper really lacks a reason to exist. What it currently does could also be handled by the constructor or a factory function/method, maybe as a class method of `Movie`. If you intend to use your wrapper *generally* to separate behavior from data, see the discussion above, and pick a side. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap just one object per attribute object - it seems sort of useless. Especially since in Python you may add attributes to an object/class dynamically.
If you want to "wrap" multiple objects - dictionary/list seem as a natural choice

Comment: maybe useless - but not 'bad' ... ?

Comment: @Lucas, when you add a level of data referencing for no reason - it usually impacts execution time. For real-life code that may be bad.